# CSS @media print not working at all

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm struggling for hours now why the @media print is not working, I search on Google even on this site and nothing helped, so that's why I post this question.
I'm testing it on Google chrome print preview (ctrl p) but i also printed to page and it stays blank.

I try'd to make a separate css file and also a embedded css style into the page.

Here is my code

Headers

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css" media="print" />
```

HTML

```
<div id="bruikleenovereenkomst">
    <div id="blo_header">

    </div>

    <div id="blo_side_top"></div>
    <div id="blo_side_bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS normal styles

```
div#bruikleenovereenkomst {
    width:595px;
    height:842px;
    background-color:#fff;
    position:relative;
}

div#blo_header {
    width:100%;
    height:125px;
    background-color:#FBE983;
    z-index:9
}

div#blo_side_top {
    width:57px;
    height:420px;
    background-color:#B6CAE5;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:99;
}

div#blo_side_bottom {
    width:57px;
    height:420px;
    background-image:url(../images/leaflet.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:99;
}
```

CSS print styles (print.css) note: the div#bruikleenovereenkomst is just a black block for testing.

```
@media print{

    body {
        margin:0;
    }

    h1#logo {
        display:none;
    }

    ul#menu {
        display:none;
    }

    div#bruikleenovereenkomst {
        width:100%;
        height:500px;
        background-color:#000;
    }

    div#blo_header {
        display:none;
    }

    div#blo_side_top {
        display:none;
    }

    div#blo_side_bottom {
        display:none;
    }

}
```

All I get with printing is just a blank page.

Comment: perhaps background are not printed? Try putting some real content there and see if it works.

Comment: But i need a colored printed page.... Is there a way that i can give divs a color for printing ?

Comment: Reading other answers on stackoverflow it seems this is a setting in the browser that you cannot override with css.

Comment: ... yes i found it now, im so sorry i thought it was just the @media print doesnt working but it was just the background-color not working.

Comment: Hence why I suggested you try some real content (text) with `@media print` to check if it was only backgrounds that were a problem! :)

Comment: @user1502014 You can turn on printing background colors/images in your browser options. It's not something you can remotely override. If your colors transport an important information and you can't rely on your users to turn that option on, you will need to use something else other than background colors to transport that information. Independently from printing: You shouldn't be using colors alone to transport information anyway for good accessibility. Not everyone can see colors!

Comment: You have to tick print background in browser print settings.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you are using @media print, you need to add !important in your styles, or the page will use the element's inline styles that have higher priority.

E.g.

```
<div class="myelement1" style="display:block;">My div has an inline style.</div>
```

In @media print, add !important and be a winner

```
@media print {
   .myelement1, .myelement2 { display: none !important; }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. `!important` might be a bit much for this, since it makes styles far harder to override.

Comment: If the !important is only for @media print, it shouldn't affect the normal page styling. It's not elegant, but if you have inline styles, you need a way to overwrite them, as they're not very elegant themselves.

Comment: Well, I can't disagree on inline styles, obviously.

Comment: +1 to you man, !important was the secret I was going nuts like changing font sizes to like 500% to try and force a change. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 26):

First, I'd try adding a space after print.  May not make a difference, but.....

```
@media print {
     /*print css here*/
}
```

Next, printing in browsers usually ignores background colors.  Try using 'box-shadow'....

```
@media print {
     #bruikleenovereenkomst {
         width: 100%;
         height: 500px;
         box-shadow:  inset 0 0 0 1000px #000;
     }
}
```

Smashing Magazine has some excellent pointers:  http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/tips-and-tricks-for-print-style-sheets/
Note that they talk about printing from a Webkit browser (Chrome or Safari, for example), and attempting to force the printer to render the colors as they appear on-screen by using a separate media query.....

```
@media print and (color) {
   * {
      -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
      print-color-adjust: exact;
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: was looking for background color : ' ), no wonder I didn't see the change.

Answer (score 0):

`window.print()` is an async function, and therefor if you are managing the DOM right after calling it - you may run into such blank print issues. The solution is to move the DOM management to event callback functions for the `beforeprint` and `afterprint` events:

[onbeforeprint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeprint)
[onafterpring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint)

*Note:* register both these callbacks *before* calling the `window.print` function

Safari browser does not support these two events.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add print media style inside the div element which you print