# CSS is not applied for print

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply css for print page.

I have tried with several options like

```
<style type = "text/css">

   @media print
    {
        body {
            color : #eee !important;
            font-size : 2em;
        }
    }

</style>
```

Here is my html code inside JS

```
newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()"><div style="border-bottom : 1px solid #000;margin-bottom :20px;"><div style="" ><p><lable>Name :</lable><span><b>'+name+'</b></span></p><p><lable>Mobile Number :</lable><span><b>'+mobile_number+'</b></span></p><p><lable>Age :</lable><span><b>'+age+'</b></span></p><p><lable>Gender :</lable><span><b>'+gender+'</b></span></p></div><div class="col-md-4"><p><lable>Prescribed By :</lable><span><b>'+doctor+'</b></span></p><p><lable>Prescribed Date :</lable><span><b>'+date+'</b></span></p></div></div><div class="col-md-12"><p><lable>Illness :</lable><span><b>'+illness+'</b></span></p><p><lable>Allergy :</lable><span><b>'+allergy+'</b></span></p><p><lable>Social History :</lable><span><b>'+social_history+'</b></span></p><p><lable>Old Medicine :</lable><span><b>'+old_medicine+'</b></span></p><p><lable>Old Diagnosis :</lable><span><b>'+old_diagnosis+'</b></span></p><p><lable>New Medicine :</lable><span><b>'+new_medicine+'</b></span></p><p><lable>New Diagnosis :</lable><span><b>'+new_diagnosis+'</b></span></p></div></body></html>');
```

But didn't worked. Anybody help please ?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28596805/6108882

Comment: @UdhayTitus...I have already use `!important` in my style. But didn't work

Comment: your code is working very well can you post your html here. or check the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/ou054d27/

Comment: Udhay Titus.... I have updated my post with html code

Comment: I too can confirm that the jsfiddle given by Udhay Titus is working on Latest Firefox Deskop Browser. If just the color part isn't working then please check your print options. Print might have been set to black & white. It's just a hunch that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your css in your js surely it will works. check here https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/ou054d27/3/

```js
function printData()
{
   /*newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write('<html><style>@media print{body {color : #eee !important;font-size : 12em; padding:10px;}}</style><body onload="window.print()"><div>This is test print page.</div></body></html>');
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();*/
window.document.write('<html><style>@media print{body {color : #eee !important;font-size : 12em;border:1px solid #000; padding:77px;}}</style><body onload="window.print()"><div>This is test print page.</div></body></html>');
   window.print();
   window.close();
  
}

$('#btnPrint').on('click',function(){
printData();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="print" id="btnPrint"/>
```

Comment: `window.open("")` does not work in stack snippet (for me), and returns null. Better use `window.document.write()` and `window.print()`

Comment: @UdhayTitus...Ur's one is correct. But one ques. `float`, `border`, `padding`...aren't these attribute working for print css ? In my code it isn't working

Comment: @UdhayTitus... it works....I accept the answer...But my problem is not solved yet... Cz all css attributes are not work may b. Cz I applied `border-bottom` attribute...but not works properly...some other attributes also didn't work.

Comment: @UdhayTitus....Please another help. I want to print where two `div` with two different `color`, `background-color` and `padding`.....

Comment: Yes it works perfectly now....Use `overflow:hidden` and all the attributes work correctly.