# why does css @media print not work on some div

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

i have problem with this html code,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #div1 {position:fixed;}
    #div2 {display:none;}
    #div3 {display:none;}
    
    @media print {
    #div1 {display:none;}
    #div2 {display:none;}
    #div3 {display:block;}
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="div1">
    <div>Contents of #div1</div><br/>
    <button id="btn1">Go to #div2</button>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <div>Contents of #div2</div><br/>
    <button id="btn2">Go to #div1</button><br/><br/>
    <button id="btn3">Print</button>
  </div>
  <div id="div3">Contents of #div3</div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn1").on("click",function() {
        $("#div1").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#div2").fadeIn("fast");
      });
      $("#btn2").on("click",function() {
        $("#div2").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#div1").fadeIn("fast");
      });
      $("#btn3").on("click",function() {
        window.print();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

let me tell you what i wish to happen with this code, so, when the page load, it just shows #div1, when i click the #btn1 it hides #div1 and shows #div2, when i click #btn2 it hides #div2 and shows #div1, when i click the #btn3 it prints the page, and it should just show #div3 in the print preview page, but, the problem here is, in the print preview page, it shows #div2 and #div3, i don't know why, i just want to show the #div3 in the print preview page, anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

jquery fadein and fadeout calls changed the precedence of display property so they also appeared ,
add important in your css to override .
Ref: [CSS @media print not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942969/css-media-print-not-working-at-all)
**Change your styles like below:**

> @media print {
> #div1 {display:none !important;}
> #div2 {display:none !important;}
> #div3 {display:block;}
> }`

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
 @media print {
    #div1 {visibility:hidden; height:0; width:0}
    #div2 {visibility:hidden; height:0; width:0}
    #div3 {display:block;}
    }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn1").on("click",function() {
        $("#div1").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#div2").fadeIn("fast");
      });
      $("#btn2").on("click",function() {
        $("#div2").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#div1").fadeIn("fast");
      });
      $("#btn3").on("click",function() {
        window.print();
      });
    });
```

```css
 #div1 {position:fixed;}
    #div2 {display:none;}
    #div3 {display:none;}
    
    @media print {
    #div1 {visibility:hidden; height:0; width:0}
    #div2 {visibility:hidden; height:0; width:0}
    #div3 {display:block;}
    }
```

```html
<div id="div1">
    <div>Contents of #div1</div><br/>
    <button id="btn1">Go to #div2</button>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <div>Contents of #div2</div><br/>
    <button id="btn2">Go to #div1</button><br/><br/>
    <button id="btn3">Print</button>
  </div>
  <div id="div3">Contents of #div3</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```